# All Individual DVs significant, but overall MANOVA not significant

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, manova

I'm getting a weird result.  Please check out the SPSS output below for CONDITION.  All the DVs are showing significant results individually but the MANOVA is not significant.  I've never seen this before ... any insights you can provide would be great!

[image]
[image]